# How to calculate the pips per value in Forex

Tags: finance

I am trying to fully understand the logic behind Forex calculations. However I find myself stuck on some parameters.

Let me explain better with a real example of a trade:

- Pairs:                AUDUSD
- Date Open:            15 June 2023
- Entry Price:          0.67995
- Stop-Loss Price:      0.67771
- Take-Profit Price:    0.68876
- Lots Size (Standard): 3 Lots
- Commission Fee:       9 (3 per Lot)
- Leverage:             100
- Result of this trade: + 2652
- Result of this trade (subtracting commission fee):    + 2643

This is what **Metatrader 5** return me as result.

## Let's redo the steps together

**1. Define the Unit**

Since we are talking about a currency quoted against the dollar I will use the value **0.0001** to calculate the pips, based on [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/AUDUSD/) and its scheme. (I assume that the last digit written smaller refers to the pipettee).

In this case our data is:

```
unit = 0.0001
```

[Scheme Image here](https://i.imgur.com/lsyyril.png)

**2. Calculate Pips**

The formula to calculate the pips, if I'm not mistaken would be this:

```
pips = abs(((interest_price - entry_price) / unit))
```

- we'll use always an absolute value for simplification for this reason *abs()*.
- we'll use to round to the nearest integer.

So now we can do some math:

```
stop_pips = abs((0.67771 - 0.67995) / 0.0001)
stop_pips = abs(-0.00224 / 0.0001)
stop_pips = abs(-22.4)
stop_pips = 22.4
stop_pips = 22 pips

profit_pips = abs((0.68876 - 0.67995) / 0.0001)
profit_pips = abs(-0.00881 / 0.0001)
profit_pips = abs(88.1)
profit_pips = 88.1
profit_pips = 88 pips
```

**3. Calculate Pip Value**

Correct formula should be:

```
pip_value = (lot / current_price) * unit
```

**Lot** is the value of a lot express in unit, we'll use standard Lot:

Standard = 100 000

Mini     = 10 000

Micro    = 1 000

Nano     = 100

**current_price** as says, should be the current price. for semplifing we could use the entry price

Result:

```
pip_value = (100 000 *  0.67995) * 0.0001
pip_value = (67995) * 0.0001
pip_value = 6.7995
```

**4. Calculate PnL**

Now we can calculate the Pnl using **Pips** and **Pips Value** (for now we will omit the leverage)

```
pnl_profit = pip_value * profit_pips 
pnl_loss   = pip_value * stop_pips
```

Result using our datas:

```
pnl_profit = 6.7995 * 88
pnl_profit = 598.35

pnl_loss   = 6.7995 * 22
pnl_loss   = 149.58
```

Now there's something that i missed or i wrong in all this calculation, but i can't understand where is the error. I tried to googling but there's ton of information and formula each one different. i asked to chatGPT but his answer are alwayys wrong and differents.

Can someone explain me better why mine calculets are different from metatrader 5?

Comment: If it helps, I see that $(0.68876-0.67995)\times 3 = 0.02643$